# Entity Framework using distinct substring and charindex

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to use SQL queries with Entity framework. But I didn't find out how to use it. Basically I try to use query as follow

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SUBSTRING(KeyStr, CHARINDEX('TYPE_', KeyStr) + 5, 5) Menu_Item, 
    Content, level 
FROM
    DB.dbo.StringDB
```

Comment: *use SQL queries with Entity framework* What to you mean? How to run SQL strings with EF? Show your own first efforts, however tentative, that always clarifies what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah How to run SQL strings with EF expression much better explanation for the question. And @Haitham suggest right solution to me. Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using the following code:

Assuming you have a class called `Result` which has the following declaration

```
public class Result
{
 public string Menu_Item{get;set;}
 public string Content{get;set;}
 public string level{get;set;}
}
```

To retrieve the results using SQL Query:

```
var sql = @"SELECT DISTINCT 
    SUBSTRING(KeyStr, CHARINDEX('TYPE_', KeyStr) + 5, 5) Menu_Item, 
    Content, level 
FROM
    DB.dbo.StringDB";
var results = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Result>(sql);
```

This should return a list of `Result` object